# Chutzpah Visual Studio Code Coverage issue

Tags: jasmine, code-coverage, chutzpah

Im running Jasmine Unit Test using Chutzpah and trying to get a code coverage for the same ( Using Visual Studi0 2015), but i see this in Code Coverage Results Window , any help is appreciated

"Empty results generated: No binaries were instrumented. Make sure the tests ran, required binaries were loaded, had matching symbol files, and were not excluded through custom settings. For more information see http://go.microsoft.com/fwlink/?LinkID=253731"

Answer (score 0):

Chutzpah code coverage does not integrate into that window. Chutzpah will open a new HTML file with its coverage results. Are you not seeing that?

Comment: No, From Visual Studio it is not opening a new HTML .... though i see code coverage result when i run from console but with a message........"Log Message: waiting for blanket... from <mypath>"

.....Also , if Chutzpah relies on opening an HTML for code coverage results ,im not sure how will it work with VSO build integration..... Would appreciate if you could throw some light on VSO integration too.Thanks Much

Comment: It does not work with VSO build integration unless you write your own step to parse the html, json or LVOV files that chutzpah can build

Comment: I use Run Chutzpah With => Coverage on my test folder. Where should the html file be located and how to I make VisualStudio 2015 Community to open it?

Comment: It should generate it and open it if it succeeds in running coverage

Comment: *facepalm* Coverage has been disabled in the configuration file, see my answer.

Answer (score 0):

For me the issue was that coverage has been disabled in the chutzpah configuration file:

> "EnableCodeCoverage": "false"

See https://chutzpah.codeplex.com/wikipage?title=Chutzpah.json%20Settings%20File

(A colleague of mine originally created the setup and I did not yet know about that option in the configuration file.)

Suggestion: The VisualStuio extension should show a message "Coverage is disabled in configuration file" for that case if one uses the Action
Run Chutzpah With => Coverage